# How did the Master return in season 8?

Tags: doctor-who

Any classic Whovian will know that the Master is never dead, just renegotiating his contract with life.  I just want to know how the writers justified his return as the Mistress in season 8.  What in-universe reason is there behind the Master's return?

Comment: Do they ever explain how the Master returns?

Comment: Big spoiler in the headline!

Comment: Season 8 was three years ago.  There has to be a statute of limitations on expecting a spoiler warning.  P.S.  Rosebud is a sleigh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doctor answer this question in the final episode of season 10

Explanation

> The Master was last seen, in a semi resurected state charging into Gallifrey in "The End of Time".  The Doctor assumes that Gallifreyans cured the master of his problem (semi resurected state) then kicked him out Gallifrey.

Corresponding Transcript

> Doctor : The last time I saw you, you were on your way to Gallifrey.
>   Master : Well, I didn't stay why would I stay?
>   Doctor : So they cured your little condition and kicked you out.
>   Master : It was a mutual kicking me out

Moreover

> This Master is killed in the last episode of season 10. It is currently unknown if he regenerated into Missy or if there is another regeneration between them

Comment: Interesting. When I heard that exchange, my immediate thought was that the "condition" was the madenning drumbeat they instilled in him from the vortex. This makes more sense though.

Comment: I don't think there is a clear answer wether the drumbeat is still there. But It might have been cured too.  Missy doesn't seem affected. That being said, the Master did had his signature beat in his musical theme in the last episodes.

Comment: "*Moreover, it is currently unknown...*" - yes, it is known, because they had a whole conversation about it in the last episode of season 10.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Although they had a whole conversation about it, you can't assume anything. Missy clearly didn't remember any of this happening, so she can't have remembered the regeneration either.

Comment: @MrLister she had some memories from his time. And besides, I recall him specifically asking her if she is who he regenerates into next.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a particular source, but the general context of the episode and subtext implies that the master turned into missy at the end of that episode. Seeing as how the nethershere:

> Was also a secret cybermen construction project

It is likely that the master left the ship and went off into space at that moment to construct the nethersphere. There is likely no delay considering the direct relation of the two projects the master/missy engaged in.

The other answer seems to clear up how he got trapped around a black hole but I never saw the end of time. I've watched all the episodes but missed that one. As far as I've ever known he:

> was shot dead by his assistant at the end of season 3 (which I assumed prompted his regeneration into Missy).

Comment: The Master didn't regenerate at the end of season 3, he refused and died a "final" death to spite the Doctor. He came back later of course, in The End of Time.

Comment: @JDoe well...  i assumed at the appearance of missy that he regenerated in secret. to be fair... I assumed the tardis regenerated beings as back then that was my impression.